# JavaScript : 64 bits repercussions on numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, 64-bit

I'm reading **Eloquent JavaScript**, and i got "stuck" in this explanation, at first i thought i'd skip it, but then i tried to come back to it, and i cant understand it, i tried googling 64 bits repercussions and stuff like that but i failed to find an answer.

I just don't get some stuff such as, what is `10^3?` why is it limited with three decimal digits? I tried typing `1.99999999999` and it worked, is there any place where i can understand this sentence fully without skipping it? I read somewhere that javascript has problems with approximation, like `2.000000000` may be `2.000000000001` which could lead problems, but this part of the  book doesnt seem any similar to that to me.

Any help appreciated thanks.

This is the part i dont understand from [this book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html)

```
This is what 144 looks like in bits:

0100000001100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The number above has 64 bits. Numbers in JavaScript always do. This has one important repercussion: There is a limited amount of different numbers that can be expressed. With three decimal digits, only the numbers 0 to 999 can be written, which is 10^3 = 1000 different numbers. With 64 binary digits, 2^64 different numbers can be written. This is a lot, more than 10^19 (a one with nineteen zeroes).

Not all whole numbers below 10^19 fit in a JavaScript number though. For one, there are also negative numbers, so one of the bits has to be used to store the sign of the number. A bigger issue is that non-whole numbers must also be represented. To do this, 11 bits are used to store the position of the fractional dot within the number.

That leaves 52 bits. Any whole number less than 2^52 (which is more than 10^15) will safely fit in a JavaScript number. In most cases, the numbers we are using stay well below that, so we do not have to concern ourselves with bits at all. Which is good. I have nothing in particular against bits, but you do need a terrible lot of them to get anything done. When at all possible, it is more pleasant to deal with bigger things.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repercussion is just part of the English sentence, it's not a technical term: 'this has one important repercussion' simply means that he's going to point out an important effect of what he's been talking about, in this case that javascript can only express a limited amount of numbers, and we can calculate that amount.

Ten to the power of three (i.e. ten cubed) is 1000, that's just basic maths. He's using that as an example, to explain how many numbers can be written with just three digits (1000 can be written, i.e. all of the numbers from 0 to 999). Likewise, if you had four digits, you could write ten to the power of four numbers (10,000, i.e. all of the numbers from 0 to 9999). It's ten to the power of something because we use the decimal number system which, by definition, is based on powers of ten (look up number/base systems, if you're still unsure: decimal, binary, hexadecimal and octal are the ones most often used in computing).

Then he goes on to talk about binary numbers, which the number system in javascript (and virtually all programming languages) uses: rather than 10 to the power of something, with binary it's 2 to the power of something, because binary is base 2, whereas decimal is base 10. So, again, when you want to find the amount of numbers you can express, you work out the base to the power of the number of digits you have, so because javascript can store 64 binary ('base 2') digits, we'd need to work out 2 to the power of 64, which happens to be a very big number -- try it in your calculator or on Google (enter 2^64 into the search box)!

However, as he says, in reality not all of these are available, because of how decimal and negative numbers are stored. If you're interested in more detail, I'd recommend that you read the book *Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software* by Charles Petzold, because he gives solid but simple explanations for someone new to this. On the bright side, you very rarely need to know the internal details of the javascript number system in order to write good javascript! But all knowledge is good.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly simple. Open your console and type:

```
0.1+0.2
```

This will be `0.30000000000000004` according to JS. That's its problem with approximation. That's because JS uses [the IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) spec for floats.
More on that topic [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/crock-on-floating-points-in-javascript)

10^3 is `Math.pow(10,3)` in JS, which is `10*10*10` or `+('10' + '0' + '0')`, which is 1000. Hence three decimal (10 possible number chars (0-9)) allow for 10*10*10 combinations, rangeing from 000 to 999 ===> 1000 combinations.
JavaScript doesn't limit you to three decimal digits, it has 64 bit numbers, and uses 11 bits to position the decimal dot.

The name *"floating point"* is a clue, here. The decimal dot can *float*. Instead of using a fixed number of bits to represent the whole number, and then a fixed number of bits to specify the non-whole part:

```
//pseudo: assume 16 bits
00000011 00000000
```

This would represent 3, if the decimal point was fixed (The middle of the bits is the point). that's not ideal, so the point's position can *float* in JS:

```
//50 zeroes
...11 00000000000
```

The last 11 bits hold the dot position, in this case `3` is a whole number, so there is no  decimal point.

When you wrote `2.999999`, the number itself is represented as a whole number (bits are either 1 or 0, there's no in-between)

```
1011011100011010111111
```

Then, the last 11 bits will be:

```
00000010100
```

this moves the floating point to the 20th position:

```
10[.]11011100011010111111
```

This makes the whole number: `10`, or 2, followed by the dot and so on.

***So? What's the problem?***

Simple: though JS uses 64 bits for its numbers, 1 of those bits is used for negative/positive numbers, and 11 for the point's position, leaving you with 52 bits for the number itself, or `2^52` possible combinations of 0's and 1's (~10^15 combinations)

In itself, that sounds like plenty, but the point *floats*. Whole numbers can, indeed be huge, but for each decimal digit you add, you take away a bit, it munches away at the possible maximum value of your number.

since it's generally less harmful to loose a trillionth of something, than it is loosing a trillion of something, the bigger the number is, the floating point is pushed back, and significant digits (precision) is lost, to accomodate larger numbers but *only if needed*.